# Pyramid not auto reloading

Tags: python, pyramid

My pyramid app is not reloading when I update and save my *.mak in templates or *.py in views. I am using the following command to serve the site and have to manually kill the process and restart before the changes appear

```
pserve --reload development.ini
```

I have the following in my `development.ini` as well

```
pyramid.reload_templates = true
```

I created the app with the alchemy scaffolding

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages app
cd app
source bin/activate
which python
pcreate -s alchemy app
python setup.py develop
```

note: `which python` showed that it's pointing to the virtualenv's copy

I hardly make any major changes to any settings...

I am not sure what information I can provide that might be helpful but please leave a comment to let me know what else I can provide. Thanks

Comment: try `python setup.py develop` install your app again

Comment: Sounds like you didn't use a virtual environment.  I'd throw out your work and start over from the beginning, then follow the instructions here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/narr/install.html

Comment: @StevePiercy: I did. I left that part out. I started with `virtualenv --no-site-packages app` then `pip install pyramid` then `pcreate -s alchemy`.
@PaulYin: still doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an open bug in pyramid_mako](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_mako/issues/19), which causes that Pyramid doesn't reload templates. Downgrade your pyramid_mako to 0.3.1 version, i.e. point exact version in `setup.py`:

```
requires = [
    'pyramid',
    'pyramid_mako==0.3.1',
    'pyramid_debugtoolbar',
    'pyramid_tm',
    'SQLAlchemy',
    'transaction',
    'zope.sqlalchemy',
    'waitress',
    ]
```

As for changes in *.py, there is a solution in comments of your question.